# which one is right use of header file in C?

Tags: c++, c, header

I really want to know right way of using header file.
Belows are two ways of using header file which i think either of them is good way.

notice : Destroy.c also use stdio.h, stdlib.h
1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Please advice me. Thanks

Comment: There is no convetion on how to do this, and generally depends on the setup and purpose.

Comment: Are you using `stdio.h`, `stdlib.h`, and `struct.h` in Destroy.c?

Comment: In general your .h files shouldn't pull more header files than necessary, so if you don't need the header to define your interface and structures, don't include it. If they are needed for implementation only, then use them in each `.c` file they are required. Overusing include in the headers might cause having more code than needed in your compilation units, thus possibly unnecessarily increasing compilation time and, more importantly, leaking dependencies to other modules.

Comment: @user3595632 Unless the header file needs the `#include`s to compile/link properly, don't include them.

Comment: IMO this is an excellent question.

Comment: OT: The declaration in the header should be a protoype: `void Destroy(void);` -- otherwise, the compiler may not (and in many cases, cannot) catch wrong calls like `Destroy(42);`.

Comment: Note that in C++, an identifier like `__Card_Destroy__` is reserved for the implementation, because there are two underscores followed by a capital letter. You should use a different naming convention for include guards (ideally with randomised long strings generated automatically by your editor when you create a new header file). Not sure about C, though.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Anything containing two consecutive underscores is reserved, along with anything that starts with an underscore followed by a capital letter. This applies to both C and C++.

Comment: @T.C. Afaik, C doesn't reserve double-underscores in the middle or at the end of an identifier (but C++ does).

Comment: @mafso Ah, you are right. Both also reserves anything that starts with an underscore in file scope.

Comment: 1) don't use leading underscoress.  2) general practice is to use all caps for #defined names, 3) general practice is to #include only those header files that are actually needed  4) Destroy.h does not need any internally included header files, but the *.c files do need a number of header files included, including destroy.h.  so the #includes should be in the *.c files 5) it is (almost) always better to include the system header files before including the local header files as this will reveal, at compile time if there are any conflicts

Comment: putting the local header file includes after the system header file includes enables the local header file includes to re-define (undefine/redefine) anything in the system header files.  Placing the local header files first eliminates that capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to mention `#include` lines in each module in a way that helps document that module.  That way the next person to work on your code can look at it and see, for example, "aha, this module uses stdlib." It's a way of making your dependencies visible, both to compiler and to programmer.

So, if you use the capabilities of `stdlib` in your `Destroy.c` module mention it in an `#include` line. If you don't, leave it out.

If your `main.c` program uses the capabilities in your `Destroy.c` module, include `Destroy.h` in your `main.c`.

The same is true (in my opinion) when you decide whether to nest the `#include` of a system header file inside one of your header files. If the stuff *in your header file itself* makes use of the stuff in the system header file, include it.

This header-file pattern:

```
#ifndef MODULE_H
#define MODULE_H
  /* lots of stuff */
#endif
```

has the purpose of making it possible to mention each header file where it's needed without worrying about including it more than once.

Another person suggested presenting your `#include` lines in a conventional order, with the system includes first. That is a good idea.

All of this is simply convention, rather than hard-and-fast rules. I'm offering a convention that has worked well for teams I have served on.

**Edit** Usually `.c` and `.h` files are paired. The `.h` file contains the declarations necessary to *use* the functions in the `.c` file. Sometimes that's just a function declaration, and sometimes it also includes declarations of constants, structs, and other such things. (I am writing about the `C` language here.  In `C++` class definition rules are clearer than in `C`.)

It is rare, but not impossible, that a header file you create will use stuff from a system header file.  A case where it might: declaring a macro that does some kind of error logging.

Comment: Then, in header of module(Destroy.h in this case), Do we usually input just declaration of function??

Comment: Since using system library in header file is really rare case...(just as i think..)

Answer (score 3):

**Do not establish unnecessary dependencies!**

There is no need to include any system headers into `destroy.h`. If needed by code in  `destroy.c` include them there.

- Use header-guards.
- Only include what is needed where it is needed.
- Include system/library headers 1<sup>st</sup>. There are very rare conditions to not stick to this rule.

  **Update on why inlcude system header 1<sup>st</sup>:**

  The system headers declare the "frame-work" the program wants to use. So the program should "know" about this "frame-work" **before** declaring its own stuff, as it might rely on what the system provides.

  The systen mostly never relies on what the program provides.

  Same for libraries, from the program's perspective, those are just additions to the system.

Comment: but the destroy.c also use system header. For example, it use printf

Comment: @user3595632: As I wrote: Include the system headers needed into `destroy.c`, but not into `destoy.h` if they are are not needed there. Do not establish unnecessary dependecies!

Comment: Then, in header of module(Destroy.h in this case), Do we usually input just declaration of function?? Since using system library in header file is really rare case...(just as i think..)

Comment: As I wrote: Include what is necessary. The compiler will tell you when this is the case. For `destroy.h`: Yes, no includes are necessary there.

Comment: @user3595632: Using standard functions in a header is rare, but using types from there is not. If you need, say, `FILE *` for a declaration, you have to include `<stdio.h>` in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you should include header files only whenever you need to call a function/macro that your c file is using its prototype/definition.
So in your case, if you're using any of the stdio/stdlib/struct libraries predefined functions -like printf- in the **Destroy()** function then make sure you include them, and if you're not, then you should not include them, although you're compiler might not even warn you about it.

In addition, if this is the only function you're calling in the **main()** function, then you should not include those header files again in the **main.c** file.

Hope this helps :)